# trying to target the child elements using my parent class firstRow

Tags: html, css

- I am trying to target the child elements using my parent class **firstRow**.
- but I am not suceessful.
- I looked at the below css selectors and then only I implemented but still I am not able to target.
  https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css_selectors.asp
- can you tell me how to fix it so that in future I will fix itmyself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

```css
.firstRow div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstRow">
  <div>
    <p>test.</p>
    <p>test 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child you're trying to target is a `p` element, not `div` element:

```css
.firstRow p:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstRow">
  <div>
    <p>test.</p>
    <p>test 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child(n)` the `n^th` child element of the current element's parent, so you can use `.firstRow p:nth-child(2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.firstRow div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstRow"> <!-- parent -->
  <div> <!-- this is nth-child(1) -->
    <p>test.</p>
    <p>test 2.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div></div> <!-- this is nth-child(2) -->
</div>
```